# Passing control to a different handler in Flask (analogy from Node.js Express)

Tags: python, flask

In Express.js, one can do this...

```
app.get('/users/:id?', function(req, res, next){
    var id = req.params.id;
    if (id) {
        // do something
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

... which passes control to the next matching route in the stack of middlewares if one is found.

Is something like this possible using Python Flask? If not, what's the idiomatic way to achieve something similar?

**EDIT:**

My original question was not clear.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var app2 = express();

app.use(app2.router);

app2.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.query.orly){
        res.send('yarly.');
    }else{
        next();
    }
});

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('nowai.');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
curl localhost:3000
>>> nowai.
curl localhost:3000/?orly=1
>>> yarly.
```

This is a simple example, but the underlying capability I'm looking for is the same: Being able to pass control to the next matching route. After asking the question I found that Werkzeug would rather all routes be unique, so I'm just wondering if this is at all possible in some form.

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure what you mean. There should only be one route which matches a view function. You would normall have a route for /users and then another one for /users/<id>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is really explicit. And I'd like to think Flask is pretty pythonic that way. What I'm really trying to say is that a JS equivalent does not exist, since it is asking to cascade the same route to 2 different functions, which is not explicit.

However, you can do something similar in Flask/Python:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'], defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def catch_all(path):
    if request.get("orly") == "1":
         return "yarly"
    else catch_arbitary_path(path)

def catch_arbitary_path(path):
    pass
    #-- your code here --
```

The difference is here you declare routes that are broad (basically everything), and you handle them in a single function, and you cascade control-flow to sub-functions according to what the path is.

Answer (score 1):

[In flask there is a object called request. In request, there is a dictionary called args and in that dictionary there is a next attribute.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/reqcontext/) This next attribute allows you to move onto a new context. [Contexts are a stack, so you can push and pop them as you please.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask._app_ctx_stack) If you wanted to use a standard redirect you could say this.

```
from flask import request, url_for

def redirect_url():
    return request.args.get('next') or \
           request.referrer or \
           url_for('index')
```

A translation of your code would look like this.

```
from flask import request, url_for, _request_ctx_stack

@app.route('/user/<id>')
def users(id):
    if id:
        #do something 
    else:
        #Push onto _request_ctx_stack if you want to change the redirect
        return request.args.get('next') or \
           request.referrer
```

Comment: I think my question wasn't very well defined after more research, but in any case this doesn't seem correct. `request.args` refers to the query string parameters, and as far as I can tell, each item in each of the context stacks is meant for one request.

Comment: After seeing the accepted answer I see that I misunderstood what you were asking for. Yes, each item in the context stack is meant for a single request. My answer will start the request sequence from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I think Python decorators can work in this case:

```py
from app import app
from functools import wraps
from flask import request

def primary_handler(f):
    wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if request.get("orly") == "1":
            return "yarly"
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@app.route('/')
@primary_handler
def secondary_handler():
    return 'nowai'
```